# Parsing encoded json string in Restkit

Tags: json, ios5, restkit

Hello i am trying to parse this result from the Google Maps API,

```
{tooltipHtml:" (10.6 km / 15 mins)",polylines:[{id:"route0",points:"}psuIqmvu@xNnCnAHzBMvBo@??fCmA??MmDEqIHkGViHlHq`A??}DsAuAs@sAeAMAkZwY}OcP{OkOgCiCQ[cBuA??kIuE_S_KeEmDwA{B{EyIyDmHuFgL_CaIYuA?W[mCHc@??p@wANgA?oAIeAUeAKU_Aw@eAJo@z@[B{Ac@QDcVaGsAQyEM{DZaB\\wEbBU?mIrDoBb@yBRUJgKAsCe@mCoAiTkNyBqBkEkFi@a@sCqAgK_CqBMaKBoDGibAmNSOoCc@sIiAQFgD[yH[UIi@?sB\\yA@a@K??[fB??{TfIgBbAwFzD??XjBVX?X",levels:"B???BBBB???@BB???@?????BB??@???@????BB??@???@???????@?????@??@?????@?@??????????????BBBB??BB??B",numLevels:4,zoomFactor:16}]}
```

But Restkit wont accept the encoded points and gives me this error

```
E restkit.network:RKResponse.m:289 Unable to parse response body: Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.
```

My code looks like the following to parse the result

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *parsedResponse = [response parsedBody:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, that format of the answer is not JSON. In JSON format keys are placed into inverted commas: "".

See the example of true JSON:

> {"key1":5,"key2":"string_value"}

Or see true JSON from Google service example:

> {
>    "status": "OK",
>    "results": [ {
>      "types": street_address,
>      "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
>      "address_components": [ {
>        "long_name": "1600",
>        "short_name": "1600",
>        "types": street_number
>      }, {
>        "long_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
>        "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
>        "types": route
>      }, {
>        "long_name": "Mountain View",
>        "short_name": "Mountain View",
>        "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
>      }, {
>        "long_name": "California",
>        "short_name": "CA",
>        "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
>      }, {
>        "long_name": "United States",
>        "short_name": "US",
>        "types": [ "country", "political" ]
>      }, {
>        "long_name": "94043",
>        "short_name": "94043",
>        "types": postal_code
>      } ],
>      "geometry": {
>        "location": {
>          "lat": 37.4219720,
>          "lng": -122.0841430
>        },
>        "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
>        "viewport": {
>          "southwest": {
>            "lat": 37.4188244,
>            "lng": -122.0872906
>          },
>          "northeast": {
>            "lat": 37.4251196,
>            "lng": -122.0809954
>          }
>        }
>      }
>    } ]
>   }

Source from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru#JSON

For testing my JSON I usually use http://json.parser.online.fr/ (but for Google's sample answer it doesn't work properly cause of unknown keys named "type").